Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'VectorIcons' could not be found
Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'VectorIcons' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.Bridgeless mode: false. TurboModule interop: false. Modules loaded: {"NativeModules":["PlatformConstants","LogBox","Timing","AppState","SourceCode","BlobModule","WebSocketModule","DevSettings","DevToolsSettingsManager","Networking","Appearance","DevLoadingView","HeadlessJsTaskSupport","UIManager","DeviceInfo","DeviceEventManager","RNGestureHandlerModule","I18nManager"],"TurboModules":[],"NotFound":["NativePerformanceCxx","NativePerformanceObserverCxx","RedBox","BugReporting","VectorIcons"]}, js engine: hermes
LOG  Running "AssignmentProject" with {"rootTag":11}
Tried to restarting the metro and restart the project.

the 'VectorIcons' module is not registered in the native binary.

For development build you need to create apk first to do the testing, type below command to build the apk, install it on the testing device, then you can run it on development build, it will not work if you didn't install the apk
eas build --profile development --platform android
Note: keep in mind you need to create new build if you add new libraries
Reference: https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/
